# Displaying HTML Text from an embedded code block

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET web page, I retrieve some text that is HTML encoded in a code block. It is displaying the text, but not formatting it. How can I display the text with the formatting?

I have tried it with and without the HTMLDECODE, but no luck

My ASP page (this is in a repeater):

```
<ItemTemplate> 
    <div class="result" data-pageid="<%#:Item.PageId %>"
        style="<%#: getBackgroundImage(Item.ImagePath) %>" >
        <div>
            <%#: Server.HtmlDecode(Item.HighlightedText) %>
        </div>                                        
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The text is displaying like this:

The police arrested 50 `<em>protesters</em>` downtown today.

I would like it to display like this:

The police arrested 50 *protesters* downtown today.

EDIT: I have also tried `<literal>` and `<pre>` without luck.

Comment: If you view the page source, what do you see?

Comment: It looks the same as what is displaying: The police arrested 50 <em>protesters</em> downtown today. I want it to treat is as HTML though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping I wouldn't have to go to the code behind, but that is what I ended up doing. I've posted my code below, but if anyone knows how this in the ASP page using and embedded code block, I would love to hear from you.

In the asp page:

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblSearchResult" runat="server" Text="ResultText"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

And the code behind:

```
protected void pageResults_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        PageResult p = e.Item.DataItem as PageResult;
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblSearchResult")).Text = p.HighlightedText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using eval()
e.g.

<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %> for only <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Price", "{0:c}") %>
        
        '>See Details

Comment: I thought eval() was evil... ;)

Comment: strange issue, thought that might have worked. sorry.